# How to assign the position of dots on an image to its associated text label

Tags: c#, json, image-processing, bitmap

i have a C# program that processes and image and returns the position of where the dots is allocated on an image as follows

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ImageDotsToData.dots.png");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[resource.Length];
        resource.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var positions = GetDotsPositions(buffer);

        foreach (var position in positions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(position);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<Tuple<int, int>> GetDotsPositions(byte[] imgData)
    {
        int HEIGHT = 400;
        int WIDTH = 600;

        List<Tuple<int, int>> positions = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        using (Stream bmpStream = new MemoryStream(imgData))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(bmpStream);
            bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        }

        List<int> knownBlankColors = new List<int>();
        knownBlankColors.Add(Color.White.ToArgb());

        for (int x = 0; x < HEIGHT; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < WIDTH; y++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                var code = pixelColor.ToArgb();

                if (!knownBlankColors.Contains(code))
                    positions.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y));
            }
        }

        return positions;
    }
}
```

which gives the output as follows:

```
(114, 33)
(114, 34)
(114, 35)
(114, 36)
(114, 37)
(114, 38)
(114, 39)
(114, 40)
(115, 33)
(115, 34)
(115, 35)
(115, 36)
(115, 37)
(115, 38)
(115, 39)
(115, 40)
(116, 33)
(116, 34)
```

etc etc
for the following image[image]

now my question is how do i assign the position of the dots to a label that match the bellow image in json
[image]
as you can see in the image that Row1 has a dot at position (114,33)

so how do i assign the labels to each of the dot position to give me a result like 
{"Row1":"(114, 33)"}

Please not that each label text has to be hard coded in

Answer (score 0):

If your rows are even in width, then it is basic match.

1. Divide your image height by the number of rows and assign to a variable `rowHeight`
2. Then

```
 // if y > 0 and y < rowHeight, then it belongs to Row 1
 if( y > ((i-1) * rowHeight) && y < (i * rowHeight)) { 
      return i;
 }
```

You can then use the I to create your new collection, or print it.